# EditorJS autofocus on click

Tags: javascript, editorjs

I`m using EditorJS (https://editorjs.io/)

I have a hidden div with editor holder in it and a separate button (Add new for ex)
I need this div to appear when user click on the button

everything is working fine

but I can't set up autofocus so that the user doesn't click on the holder to start working with editor

i tried doing

```
setTimeout(function(){ $('#editor').click()}, 100);
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your growth correctly
https://editorjs.io/configuration#autofocus

There a config key:

```
const editor = new EditorJS(
  autofocus: true
})
```

Comment: Yes. But how to achieve it after button click?

Comment: just editor.focus();

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the solution:

```
<div id="editorjs"></div>
<button id="focus">focus</button>
```

And initialization :

```
const editor = new EditorJS({ 
  
  
  holder: 'editorjs', 
  
  onReady: function () {
    const btn = document.querySelector("#focus");
    btn.addEventListener("click", () => editor.focus())
  }

})
```

And link for example : https://codepen.io/Ashley100/pen/mdEqoRY?editors=1010